# Encoding response value to base64 and using it on another test

Tags: testing, jmeter, base64

I'm trying to do some testing using JMeter but I'm facing an issue trying to do some complex stuff.

I have a login HTTP request test that comes back with a response which includes an `auth_token`. I need to add `":"` at the end and encode it to base64 to use that value on the request of another test.

I've been reading that it can be done using BeanShell but I could not achieve it yet. I will appreciate if someone could give me some steps to perform this task.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you know how to get this `auth_token` into a JMeter Variable via i.e. [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)

If you're have [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) installed  - you can use [__base64Encode()](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#base64Encodesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup) function like:

```
${__base64Encode(${auth_token},auth_token_encoded)}
```

If you don't have the plugins/cannot have/don't want to have - here is how to do it with Beanshell.

1. Add Beanshell PostProcessor somewhere after Regular Expression Extractor (or other PostProcessor you're using to fetch the `auth_token` value
2. Put the following code into the Beanshell PostProcessor "Script" area:

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.Base64Encoder;

   String auth_token = vars.get("auth_token");
   String auth_token_encoded = Base64Encoder.encode(auth_token);
   vars.put("auth_token_encoded", auth_token_encoded);
   ```

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) to get started with Beanshell scripting.

Both cases assume:

- you have "auth_token" value stored in `${auth_token}` JMeter Variable
- you will be able to access the encoded value as `${auth_token_encoded}`

Comment: Hi Dmitri. Thanks for your response. This is the auth token Im trying to extract.  http://screencast.com/t/agRTNKEct. I am trying to extract it using this regular expression extractor. http://screencast.com/t/xx7wA3Xx and convert it to base64 using this beanshell post processor.  http://screencast.com/t/lpPEE7fhd. I created a variable to store it once encoded but still cannot make it work.  http://screencast.com/t/2WuXOiuk. Any ideas? – user6519108 13 mins ago

Comment: I have an idea: you don't have any ideas regarding how to use regular expressions. Where did you get that `meta-content` from? Another stackoverflow post? Either change your regex to something like: `"auth_token": "(.+?)"` or use [JSON Path Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar test case where I need to put a file as Base64 encoded String into the body of a HTTP Request.

Instead of a BeanShell I used the groovy script functionality¹:

```
{
    "example": "${__groovy(new File('${SCRIPT_PATH}/test.file').bytes.encodeBase64())}"
}
```

If you already have a String this snippet would work similar:

```
{
    "example": "${__groovy('string to encode'.bytes.encodeBase64())}"
}
```

Or this is the usage with a user defined variable:

```
{
    "example": "${__groovy('${STRING_VARIABLE}'.bytes.encodeBase64())}"
}
```

---

¹ `${SCRIPT_PATH}` is a user defined variable pointing – in my case – to the folder of the loaded jmx-file: `${__BeanShell(org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();)}${__BeanShell(File.separator,)}`

Comment: Hello Sven! It's been ages now since your answer, but using the groovy script makes the message COMPLETELY disappear! Please, is there a way to solve this issue?